# How to define type of object property without using an interface

Tags: typescript

tickList is (or should be) an Array of type number

```
fpsObject = {
  maxSamples: 100,
  tickIndex: 0,
  tickSum: 0,
  tickList: []
}
```

Can I enforce this type without creating an interface? Or must I create an interface to do this? Thanks in advance. I would rather avoid creating an interface if at all possible. I've got too many interface files already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way also:

```
const fpsObject = {
  maxSamples: 100,
  tickIndex: 0,
  tickSum: 0,
  tickList: Array<number>()
}
console.log(fpsObject)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use as to type it:

```
const fpsObject = {
  maxSamples: 100,
  tickIndex: 0,
  tickSum: 0,
  tickList: [] as number[]
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgBwgeQEYCsCmxYF4YDeAUDDALYCGAHgMoVkIA2mEAXDAIwAMXANCTCgBLYAGsAkmAAmmKuz4DhYmgFcy8-qSWiAMkOjsA2gF0YFCDDBrUmAE4miAXyA)

Comment: thanks, looks a tad messy but better than a kick up the pants :D